# Laravel Lumen call artisan command from route

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, lumen

In Laravel, [I can do this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#calling-commands-via-code) to call an `Artisan` command from a route:

```
Route::get('/foo', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('email:send', [
        'user' => 1, '--queue' => 'default'
    ]);

    //
});
```

But I can't find an obvious way to do this in the Lumen framework. The error thrown is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Artisan' not found
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This was actually very simple. Just be sure to `use` the `Artisan Facade` class wherever needed:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
...
public function process()
{
    Artisan::call('command');
}
```

I assumed the normal Laravel facades weren't available in the framework by default but they are.

Also, in `bootstrap/app.php`, `$app->withFacades();` must be uncommented as @tptcat reminded me in the comments.

Comment: Correct. As long as you uncomment `$app->withFacades();` in `/bootstrap/app.php`. Also, you could do this in `routes.php` as long as you do `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan`. And there's no need to say `as Artisan` in either case.

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. I actually wanted to use it in a `Controller` to begin with - the example in the Laravel docs was just for a `Route` though.

Answer (score 5):

This is just an extension, maybe not the best way. But what if you just dont want to use the Facade way? Well you can do it via the `Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel`.

```
// See what Artisan facade provides in `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan`
// and thats: `Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel`
app('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->call('command');
```

Or create an alias for the `Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel`:

```
// In your service provider or bootstrap/app.php create the alias
$this->app->alias('arti', 'Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel');

// now the 'artisan' alias is available in the container
app('arti')->call('command');
```